# sysrq won't reboot with a keystroke, but will with echo "b" > /proc/sysrq-trigger

Tags: linux, keyboard, laptop, magic-sysrq

CentOS 6.2, 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 laptop. SysRQ is enabled for keyboard input, as is witnessed by:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
1
```

Common Magic SysRQ Keys are working such as <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>sysrq</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>. However, other keystrokes do not appear to be working. Most notably, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>sysrq</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> for rebooting. However, I can get the reboot SysRQ option to work via `echo "b" > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

I realize that `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` does not need to be enabled in order for echoing options to `sysrq-trigger` to work, so I'm assuming that there's some problem with the Magic SysRQ key combination actually being signaled.

What would be causing the inability for some SysRQ keystrokes to work, but others not? And yet manually sending the option to `sysrq-triggers` *will* work?

## EDIT 1

Shamefully, I left out some information in the above question. Yes, I'm using a laptop, but I'm also using an external keyboard. I don't think I've used the built-in keyboard on my Dell XPS 1530 for years so it didn't even register in my mind that the keyboard situation could be part of the issue.

On the Dell XPS 1530's built-in keyboard, the SysRQ key is technically a function key. "SysRQ" is printed in blue to signal that a person, theoretically, should press the `Fn` key to access it. However, when using the built-in keyboard, you merely have to press the standard <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>sysrq</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> combination to cause a reboot! No function key required.

My external keyboard is a Logitech Illuminated Keyboard, and it has its own `FN` key on it. However, SysRQ is not apparently mapped as an alternate key. I say "apparently" because `SysRQ` isn't actually printed on ***any*** of the keys. Instead, I assumed that `Print Screen` was the SysRQ key because that's what SysRQ has shared a key with in recent years. That seems to have been a fair assumption because, as I tested things out, most Magic SysRQ key combinations work using that key as <kbd>SysRQ</kbd>.

Nevertheless, I've tried a plethora of combinations using the external keyboard, and none of them seem to work with the re[B]oot Magic SysRQ key. I know <kbd>alt</kbd> works and I know <kbd>print screen</kbd> works as the SysRQ key without need for the function key on the external keyboard. It just appears, at this moment anyway, that the <kbd>b</kbd> key is not being sent as be. Is there any way that I can see what key code is being sent to my terminal as I type on a keyboard?

Comment: Laptop or desktop?

Comment: @Gilles Laptop - but interesting that there could be a difference. I'd be fascinated to know what the distinction would imply in the scenario!

Comment: “Is there any way that I can see what key code is being sent to my terminal as I type on a keyboard?” → type `showkey` as root in a text mode console. What you type as part of an `Alt+SysRq` sequence might not register, so do some experiments with magic SysRq turned off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a typical laptop, you need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to press <kbd>SysRq</kbd>. If you also press the letter in the same movement, you end up pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>*letter*</kbd>. But several letters are mapped to numeric keypad keys when combined with <kbd>Fn</kbd>. For example, if you try to press `Alt+SysRq+U`, you end up pressing `Alt+SysRq+Num4` instead.

To avoid this pitfall, press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then a press and release <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (using <kbd>Fn</kbd> if necessary), then press and release the magic SysRq function letter, and finally release <kbd>Alt</kbd>. For example: hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>, press and release <kbd>Del</kbd>, release <kbd>Fn</kbd>, press and release <kbd>U</kbd>, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I'm not sure if that's your problem, as <kbd>B</kbd> is typically not a numpad key on laptops. It may be a vendor-specific key; if <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is not equivalent to plain <kbd>B</kbd>, then you need to release <kbd>Fn</kbd> mid-sequence.

Comment: Okay, it appears that I shamefully left out some information that is pertinent. The keyboard I'm using is an external keyboard. When using the built-in keyboard, alt-sysrq-b works perfectly. I'll add this to the post shortly...