# Why does Alt+SysRq+B not always trigger while REISU do?

Tags: linux, reboot, magic-sysrq

On many different machines, when I come across a lockup, I often use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+`REISUB` to reboot without too much losses. But I often noticed that although `REISU` commands work even when I just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> and enter them without releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>, the last one, `B`, seems to be very "lazy": I have to repeat it many times, and in fact it doesn't trigger until I do the cycle "press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>, type B, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>" multiple times (and not always the same number of times).

At first occurrences of this problem I thought it's the kernel which has locked too hard that it doesn't "see" my `B` command, but when I realized that multiple repetitions of it do allow me to trigger reboot, it now seems that it's something general. Even on a working system (be it Debian, Ubuntu, LFS etc.), I can easily reproduce this. In fact, I can even load the kernel with `init=/bin/bash` and reproduce this from this bash prompt.

Looking at serial console output, I see all the feedback on `REISU`, but only one feedback print on multiple `B` commands — when the kernel finally is convinced to do a reboot.

Why is this? Is it some kernel feature which prevents unintended reset, or maybe it's just a bug (quite strange one)?

Note that I'm using plain keyboard with no <kbd>Fn</kbd> or multimedia keys, so this question isn't a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39852/sysrq-wont-reboot-with-a-keystroke-but-will-with-echo-b-proc-sysrq-trigge).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not in software, it's in hardware.
Keyboard keys are not independent: there're about 100 keys, but only about 26 wires going into keyboard's internal controller:

[image]

<sup>(Image from [dreamstime.com](http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-images-interior-computer-keyboard-showing-connections-keys-image29969124))</sup>

This means that not all keys can be detected when simultaneously pressed. Because <kbd>RAlt</kbd> is much closer to <kbd>SysRq</kbd> than <kbd>LAlt</kbd>, I always use it to free one hand for entering chars. But it appears that on most (all?) PC keyboards <kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> doesn't send scancode of <kbd>B</kbd>!<sup>*</sup>

Why do I then finally get the reboot? It's simple: when I'm very annoyed that I can't reboot the machine with this semi-working command, I press the combo many times without too much attention, sometimes mixing presses and releases of keys — and it appears that <kbd>SysRq</kbd> isn't a normal modifier for linux, like e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> is: the magic-SysRq mode is active even after I release <kbd>SysRq</kbd> but still hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Then the sequence which appears to work is:

- Press <kbd>RAlt</kbd>
- Press <kbd>SysRq</kbd>
- Release <kbd>SysRq</kbd>
- Press <kbd>B</kbd>
- See reboot

For <kbd>LAlt</kbd> things appear much simpler: the keyboard is able to detect <kbd>B</kbd> when <kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> is held, so there's no problem, but I never noticed it before because I always used <kbd>RAlt</kbd>.

Funnily, it appears that this issue is long known, and the workaround is that same which I've discovered empirically. From kernel source tree, [Documentation/sysrq.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/sysrq.txt#L41) (emphasis mine):

> On x86   - You press the key combo 'ALT-SysRq-<command key>'. Note - Some
>              keyboards may not have a key labeled 'SysRq'. The 'SysRq' key is
>              also known as the 'Print Screen' key. **Also some keyboards cannot
>          handle so many keys being pressed at the same time, so you might
>          have better luck with "press Alt", "press SysRq", "release SysRq",
>          "press <command key>", release everything.**

So, looks like this trick is an official recommendation, not an unreliable side effect of implementation.

<sub>*</sub><sub>I've actually checked this with a simple DOS program which reports every scan code the [i8042](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8042) gives on each IRQ1</sub>

Comment: Yep! There are "gaming" or "professional" keyboards that _do_ register all keys separately. Search for "n-key rollover", or _NKRO_. ([Das Keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/) is one example. I have no affiliation with them except I love mine.)