# SysRQ+B (boot) not working but O (turning off) is

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, reboot, magic-sysrq

For some reason, my Linux machine will properly turn off when striking <kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, but **won't** reboot as expected when doing <kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Both of these ones show up in the help message (with SysRq+H) and all my SysRq options are enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
1
```

I use a 11-years-old machine (Intel Q9550 / ASUS P5E3, assembled by myself) that currently runs a `Fedora 31` linux distribution, but the problems shows up at least since `Fedora 25`. I first suspected the custom kernels from this distribution to be the cause, but it seems to occur with self-compiled genuine kernels too.

It also used to work in the past and with other distribs such as Knoppix, but I can't remember when it started to happen.

Nothing happens nor shows up when I do SysRq+B, neither on console nor dmesg log. Every other option (in particular, R, E, I or S) seems to be OK, and to produce log trafic. Does anybody know what could cause the reboot operation to be disabled ?

This leads my to a "secondary" question:

Inside the kernel source, at rows `447` and `469` of `drivers/tty/sysrq.c`, I can see:

```c
        &sysrq_reboot_op,               /* b */

…

        /* o: This will often be registered as 'Off' at init time */
        NULL,                           /* o */
```

So rebooting (which not currently works for me) is supposed to be always defined by default while turning off (which does work) is set to NULL, then defined at init time. I couldn't find which is this actor, nor at what exact time this powering off option is enabled. Could you help me on this too ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT : lastest kernel at write time is `5.5.1` but the code quoted above belongs to `5.4.15` and older, and I'm running the Redhat's `5.4.15-200.fc31.x86_64` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it turns out to be due to the same problem than in this [related entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143935/why-does-altsysrqb-not-always-trigger-while-reisu-do). It worked by releasing <kbd>Syst</kbd> while maintaining <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>B</kbd>.

This surprises me a little bit because I use a desktop machine using a PS/2 keyboard port (not an embedded laptop keyboard). I used to work with a cheap Logitech keyboard that has always been a pain, but seemed to do the job anyway. When this keyboard died, I installed back an old Compaq keyboard from years 2K (Model **KB-9963**) that works pretty well and is much pleasant to use, but visibly suffers from the same problem.