# How to reboot centos with hotkeys?

Tags: centos

I stuck on installation in centos with some soft on error. How I can exit of installation proccess or reboot server?

Comment: What is a “soft on error”? Is the installer program still responding?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).

> The magic SysRq key is a key combination understood by the Linux kernel, which allows the user to perform various low-level commands regardless of the system's state. It is often used to recover from freezes, or to reboot a computer without corrupting the filesystem.

- Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Press and release the key labeled <kbd>SysRq</kbd>
- Press and release <kbd>U</kbd>. This saves any unsaved buffers to the disk, then forcibly remounts all filesystems read-only.
- Wait until you see a message “Emergency Remount R/O” on the console. If you can't see the console, wait until all disk activity has stopped.
- Press <kbd>B</kbd> and release the keys. Your computer will reboot.

Comment: IDK, isnot wrking PrntScrn+b or maybe its just because of laptop keyboard.

Comment: You need to hold down Alt+PrntScrn+B. Either you missed the Alt key or you didn't post that in your comment. By the way, steps are: 
    1-Hold down the Alt and SysRq (Print Screen) keys.
    2-While holding those down, type the following keys in order, several seconds apart: REISUB
    3-Computer should reboot.

Comment: Yep, it works. but looks like I reboot myself . LOL. how to do it in KRDC?

Comment: I don't think that will work remotley, you will either need to be in the physical machine or find/develop a program that launches that sequence remotely.

Comment: Trying to reboot VDS in hosting panel, but its not rebooting the OS so I get same stuck error , dont know what to do....

Comment: @user103712 On a laptop, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39852/sysrq-wont-reboot-with-a-keystroke-but-will-with-echo-b-proc-sysrq-trigge/39854#39854