# *DM Login problems

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, login, kdm

I got my laptop battery accidently disconnected, while the laptop was suspended to RAM. And now I'm experiencing these problems:
When I'm trying to login to the system using sddm or kdm:
after I enter my password - I'm getting mouse cursor and default wallpaper displayed and nothing happens after that.

It doesn't matter if I'm trying to login to kde or to TWM.

I've created a new user to test whether is it related to some user settings. It's not. The same thing happens for a new user.

I can login to the tty console.

I can perform startx and startkde with root credentionals and kde works just fine.

But if I'm performing startx with standart user credentionals - twm starts and then my laptop ignoring any input (besides power button).

My ~/.xsession-errors contains only the following line:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

I've already done fsck.

Do you have any idea what I'm dealing with here?

**UPD:**

Some (probably relevant) info from journalctl. After the login attempt with sddm, I'm getting:

> dbus: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
>   sddm-helper: pam_systemd(sddm:session): failed to create session: connection timed out

Comment: When you say that your laptop ignores any input, does that include Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to a different console? Before rebooting, press [Alt+SysRq+U](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39854) to improve the chances that the log file will be written out, then use Alt+SysRq+B to reboot if it works. After rebooting, post the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` from the attempt that crashed. If you can arrange it, log into your laptop from another machine with SSH and see if it still responds when the console is frozen.

Comment: I mean **any**, including Ctrl+Alt+F1. Well, I've solved the main problem, so I think this is irrelevant for now, but thank you anyway for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite counterintuitive for me, but reinstalling sudo and editing sudoers file helped.